# Best way to use mysql node module across several servers

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I am running around 100 servers for one of my node applications. Each of which allows users to login. Each of these servers currently has a setup like this:

```
mysql.createPool({
    port: xx,
    connectionLimit: 20,
    host: "xxx",
    user: "xxx",
    password: "xxx",
    database: "xxx",
    charset: "utf8mb4"
});
```

And I have this function that calls stored procedures on the database:

```
var queries = ["test_1", "test_2"];
```

This function takes parameters like these: ["alex", "password"]

```
this.call = function(index, data, callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            if (connection) connection.destroy();
            if (callback) callback(err);
        } else {
            try {
                var statement = "CALL " + context.queries[index] + "(";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
                    statement += mysql.escape(data[i]) + (i<data.length-1?",":"");
                }
                statement += ")";
                connection.query({
                    sql: statement,
                    timeout: 4000
                }, function(error, response, fields) {
                    connection.destroy();
                    if (callback) callback(error, response, fields);
                });
            } catch (e) {
                connection.destroy();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

As you can see, I create the connection and then destroy it again once it has been used to free it up for use. The issue that I am facing right now is that when I have over 3000-5000 CCU the connections keep opening and stay open. Is there a better way to implement this system across several node servers?

Using a pool and keeping the connections open is not an option since i have around 100 servers. And i cant keep 100 idle connections open at all times.

Answer (score 1):

You're using connection pooling and the purpose of that is the create a "pool" of open connections to the database (that stay open and can be reused in future queries).  The default connection size for a pool is 10.  So, in your world, it appears that each server's pool would have 10 open connections.

To use fewer concurrent connections, you can either stop using pooling at all (so an idle server will hold no open connections) or you can reduce the size of the connection pool with the [`connectionLimit` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pool-options) when creating the pool.

To allow the connection pool to do its thing properly, you would use `connection.release()`, not `connection.destroy()`.

If you are setting the pool to be small and/or are using `connection.destroy()` and you still see connections continue to climb based on the number of clients, then you may have a connection leak - some place in the code that is not properly cleaning up a connection that is no longer being used.

You could add debugging to the connection pool to listen and log the [`acquire`, `connection`, `enqueue` and `release` events on the pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#pool-events) to get a better idea what's happening on the connection pool.

Here's one discussion of [debugging a connection leak](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/973).

Comment: The reason I am using a Pool is in case 2 users login at the same time on the same node server. I use destroy because i dont want the connection to be kept alive after its used

Comment: @user3024235 - It doesn't seem like you're using the pool for anything - it's just a waste then.  You can just make a new connection when you need it and then destroy it when done if you never want to cache it for reuse (that's what the pool is for).  If you're always using `.destroy()`, then the pool is doing nothing.  In your current code, you will need to do some debugging on the pool and find out where connections are not being freed.